# Plain javascript equivalent of $(document).on(event) with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert a jQuery event handler to pure javascript. There are loads of a particular selector on the page, so this was designed with only one event targeting document with that selector:

```
$(document).on("click", selectorString, function(event) {
 // do stuff
});
```

Where `selector` is a list of selectors as a string "`.one, .two, .three`".

I'm struggling to replicate this without jQuery though:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if (elementHasClass(event.target, selectorString) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

But this doesn't have the desired behaviour, as the listener is only on the `document` element, rather than the selected element *within* the document. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: That's because you need to create your own event delegation now. https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your problem is that it doesn't work on nested elements.

For instance, if you click on a nested `span` element that has a parent with the specified class, then it doesn't work because you are merely checking to see if the `span` element (which is `event.target`) has the class.

To resolve this, you could essentially delegate the event and check to see if any of the `event.target` element's parent's elements have the specified class:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/w1Lr06a5/)

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var target = e.target;

    while (target && target.parentNode !== document) {
        target = target.parentNode;
        if (!target) { return; } // If element doesn't exist

        if (target.classList.contains('target')){
            // do stuff
            console.log(e.target);
        }
    }
});
```